# Flutter: Dropdown requires two taps to open when textfield has focus

Tags: flutter

I have a form with multiple text fields and dropdowns. When I switch the focus between different textfields, the focus changes as expected.

But when a textfield has focus and right after I tap on a dropdown, the soft keyboard is dismissed and the focus is back in the textfield. The dropdown does not open on first tap. Only when I tap the dropdown again the textfield looses focus and the dropdown opens.

When the focus was not in the textfield before, tapping once on the dropdown opens it as expected.

Is there a way the make the dropdown open on first tap?

Answer (score -1):

Same question asked here:

[Flutter / Android - moving focus from a dropdownbutton to a textField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534205/flutter-android-moving-focus-from-a-dropdownbutton-to-a-textfield)

And there is also some discussion on it here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22075

Comment: Thank you, Dan. I had a look at the linked question and its answer. To be specific, we're using DropdownButtonFormField. I tried the suggested workaround but its onChange listener only fires when the user selects a value. For this the dropdown must already be open, which currently requires two taps.